# Navbar icon image not showing up

Tags: html, css

I'm having some trouble with getting my icon to show up in the navbar.
It just resorts to the alt instead of showing the image below:

[image]

I managed to get it to work very mysteriously by changing the margins around randomly. No clue what I did to make it work.

Restarted the server and the problem has shown up again.

Any help is appreciated.

Update: The file itself seems to not work with this code. Every other similar image using the same code and directory/image host works just fine.

```css
body {
  background: url('redpattern.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
  background-size: 2900px 1000px;
/*  color: #333333;*/
  margin-top: 5rem;
}


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #444444;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}


bg-steel {
  color: #b52525;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {
  color: #208ee8;
}

.site-header .navbar-nav .nav-link.active {
  font-weight: 5500;
}

.content-section {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.article-title {
  ;
}

a.article-title:hover {
  color: #418ac9;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-content {
  white-space: pre-line;
}

.article-img {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.article-metadata {
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e3e3
}

.article-metadata a:hover {
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.article-svg {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.account-img {
  height: 125px;
  width: 125px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.account-heading {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top" style="background-color:#660000;">
    <div class="container" id="topnavbar">
      <a class="navbar-left mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">
        <img src="logo.png" width="200" height="100" alt="image"/></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
        <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-rules' %}">Rules</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register'%}">Register</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Not a python problem!

Comment: removed python/django. thanks

Comment: I tried your code and it works on my machine.

Comment: Works when I try it out as well.

Comment: Still trying, nothing seems to work. Doesn't show in any browser.

Comment: Do you use django if so then where your logo.png located?

Comment: @ShafikurRahman  Same folder as the html file. It worked with the same exact code by playing with the margins but somehow it's not working now. Thank you

Comment: @lexlikely Change the logo url and see:
https://via.placeholder.com/200x100.png
This worked in my local

Comment: @pasan_jg this image works. I've tried uploading my image to imgur and using that. no luck. might I add that the image is half transparent, could this be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to place image file in `project_directory/static` then in navbar use

```
{% load static %} 
<img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" width="200" height="100" alt="image"/></a>
```

Comment: Do I need to further specify where to find the file? `<a class="navbar-left mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">
        <img src="{% static 'logo.png' %}" width="200" height="100" alt="image"/></a>` Sadly, no change. Thank you

Comment: no just change the line I mentioned. You image will be shown

Comment: I changed the code with no results. I appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Comment: The problem is static files loading. Please find a tutorial on how Django static files work.

Comment: In the other comments someone suggested that I use a different default logo from a url. This logo worked. However, when I upload my image and use a url I get the same problem as before. The 403 I ran was with the imgur link as the src. Doesn't this indicate it's a problem with the image itself? Thank you again

Comment: url works fine. But when you works with static files then django handle this in own ways

Comment: one url works and the other doesn't. no clue why the code can't process this image specifically

Comment: you may take idea from this repo https://github.com/shafikshaon/meal_hisab/blob/master/templates/base.html#L10

Answer (score -1):

can you inspect your  tag?

it may cause by the wrong directory!